# Detached HTMLElements in angular apps and memory leaks

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, htmlelements

So, we have an angular app (v12) that is experiencing memory leaks (sluggish over time).

We are using the MS Edge detached elements dev tool to see what is happening and provide some visibility which is great. However it's giving us a heap of Detached HTMLElement memory references, yet we cannot work out what it is it they are referring to.

When we follow the tree down to what it's, im assuming is the problem, we end up with something like this: [image]

My question is: can someone interpret this for me please? And/or suggest something/anything that might help point me in the general direction of fixing this...

Thanks for your help (again)